# How to show recent content from block?

Tags: block, concrete5

I'm using concrete5.6.1.2.
I have a single page and there is a block on it.
I want to show content from block in single page to shown in home.
The problem is how to show recent content from a block in another page?
I have searched arround concrete documentation but i cannot find what i want.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking for... are you asking for a block that pulls the most recent content from any other page or are you just wanting a block showing the same content on two pages?

Comment: I want to pulls the most recent content from any other page.

Answer (score 0):

The code to programmatically "get" a block from another page is this:

```
$page = Page::getByPath('/your/page');
$blocks = $page->getBlocks('Main'); //<--change this to the name of the area the block is in
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
    $bi = $block->getInstance();
    //do something...
}
```

But the "do something" part of that code depends on what exactly you're trying to do. Your question is "...show recent content from a block...", and every piece of that sentence requires clarification:

- What exactly do you mean by "recent"? How are you determining what the most recent content is? Is it the first block on the page? Or the last block on the page? Or is this a special kind of blocktype that has dated information in it?
- What exactly do you mean by "content"?  Do you want all the contents of the block (exactly as it is displayed on the single_page)? Or just specific pieces of data from it?
- What exactly do you mean by "block"? What kind of block do you want to pull from? Is it a standard "content" block? Or something else (and if so, what)?

If you can clarify your requirements I can give a more specific answer.